# Can either the covariant or the contravariant version of a physical tensor be more fundamental?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, covariance

This question may be too subjective, but here goes:

Essentially any physically interesting quantity can be represented by a tensor on an inner product space or by a tensor field on a pseudo-Reimannian manifold. Any such tensor (of higher rank than scalar) can represented either with covariant indices or with contravariant indices (or mixed indices, for tensors of rank 2 or higher). It's easy to convert between these two representations by simply contracting the relevant index/indices with the metric tensor or its inverse.

For a given physical quantity (e.g. position, velocity, acceleration, force, angular velocity/momentum, torque, EM tensor, gauge potential, stress-energy tensor, etc.), can either version be considered more physically fundamental? For example, is it the case that for momentum, the covariant version $p_\mu$ is the "fundamental" tensor, while the contravariant version $p^\mu = g^{\mu \nu} p_\nu$ is the "derived" tensor - or vice versa? Or are the two versions conceptually completely symmetric?

If there is sometimes a "more fundamental" version, then is there a uniform rule or algorithm for determining which is the "fundamental" version of a given physical tensor quantity (e.g. momentum)? Or is it just entirely case-by-case?

(There are a lot of questions on Physics SE that ask whether a given physical quantity is "really" contravariant or covariant, thereby implicitly assuming that such a distinction is indeed meaningful. The discussions around these questions tend to be a bit muddled, because they combine discussion of the big-picture question outlined above with the specifics of the particular physical quantity being asked about. So I wanted to step back and just address the big-picture question on its own.)

Comment: Let’s take two specific examples in SR. Which seems more fundamental: $x^\mu=(t,x,y,z)$ or $x_\mu=(t,-x,-y,-z)$? How about $\partial_\mu=(\partial/\partial t, \partial/\partial x, \partial/\partial y, \partial/\partial z)$ or $\partial^\mu=(\partial/\partial t,-\partial/\partial x,-\partial/\partial y,-\partial/\partial z)$?

Comment: This question (v1) seems to be mostly about conventions and definitions.

Comment: @Ghoster I agree with you that $x^\mu$ seems more natural than $x_\mu$, but I don't think your second example necessarily applies, because I wouldn't describe the partial derivative as a "physical quantity" but a mathematical operation.

Comment: @Qmechanic The question is *not* asking about how anything is defined, if that's what you mean. It's asking about whether one definition can be more physically natural than another, which is a question about the underlying physics and not about how any particular term is defined.

Comment: I would say yes in the sense of "the object which requires the least amount of structure to define ought to be the fundamental one". For instance, given a curve $\gamma$ just based on the manifold structure, we get its velocity $\dot{\gamma}$. We don't get a covector naturally (unless you have a metric, or a diffeomorphic Legendre transformation lying around). Likewise, angular velocity is best thought of as a bivector, not an element of $\Bbb{R}^3$. Forces should be thought of as covector fields (conservativeness is more naturally formulated). Work done is more natural to formulate...

Comment: I'm sure people might get 'angry' by me saying that, but try doing things without a metric, and that usually reveals the more fundamental object mathematically. But, the only reason to abstain from the metric is so the foundations and concepts are clear (which I think you know). In order to link to physics, one must make measurements (i.e metrics are involved), so then we can try to link all the descriptions using the metric isomorphism.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Is momentum more naturally formulated as a covariant or a contravariant vector? ${\bf p} = m{\bf v}$ suggests contravariant, but ${\bf F} = \frac{d{\bf p}}{dt}$ suggests covariant.

Comment: momentum is better understood as a 1-form (I’ve written a whole bunch of answers about the many different things we call momentum, so you may want to look them up… but I don’t think that’s your central query). In the equation $p=mv$, the mass plays the role of the Riemannian metric.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Do you have a reference that explains that claim? ${\bf p} = m {\bf v}$ seems pretty fundamental ... if you can't even get that without invoking a particular metric, then it doesn't seem like you can do much at all with a smooth spacetime manifold without a metric.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh, I guess the point is that $p_i = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q^i}$ is more fundamental, and the usual formula ${\bf p} = m {\bf v}$ only holds because in standard Newtonian physics, the metric enters into the Langranian?

Comment: well, I certainly didn’t say throw the metric out. On the contrary, my second comment says essentially the opposite in the end. Of course, in $\Bbb{R}^3$, which is where we have derived centuries of intuition and understanding from, everything blends together structurally (mathematically speaking). We took centuries to distil things to their ‘bare-bones essentials’. Almost every mathematical classical mechanics text will allude to this viewpoint at some point. To go from velocities to momenta, you need something to convert them (a ‘scalar’ mass, or a metric, or a hyperregular Lagrangian etc).

Comment: @peek-a-boo When you say that angular momentum is a "bivector", do you mean a tensor with two antisymmetric covariant or contravariant indices? I thought that the metric-free definition of angular momentum was $\frac{d{\bf r}}{dt} = \omega({\bf r})$, but that seems to imply that angular momentum is a linear operator, not a bivector.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Similarly, is the angular momentum bivector more naturally thought of as having two covariant or contravariant indices? I believe that angular momentum cannot be formulated for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ without a metric. Abstractly, that's because angular momentum is defined as the generator of rotations, and rotations are in turn defined as linear transformations that preserve the metric. Concretely, that's because $L$ is defined to be $r \wedge p$ - but you can't wedge together a vector and a one-form because they live in different (though dual) vector spaces, so you...

Comment: @peek-a-boo need to use a metric to establish a canonical duality that allows you to convert between vectors and one-forms. But is it better to use the metric to turn $p$ contravariant or to turn $r$ covariant before wedging them together into a bivector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142791/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-tparker).